# inserting jquery into js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file that in which i want to include jquery. in order to include the jquery script i am using this clode:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

this works, I can see that incuded the script correctly. My inspector shows that it loaded the script but jquery wont work.

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you add the script tag dynamically?

Comment: How do you conclude jquery is not working?

Comment: This sounds like a race condition.   The code above loads jQuery asynchronously so, you won't be able to access jQuery until it downloads and loads.

Comment: the .js file is using a simile $(document).click(function(){ 
alert('works');
});

I have that same code in both the js file (loaded in the footer) and the html file in the body. the console error i'm getting is "$ is not defined"

Comment: did you try using jQuery instead of $ ??

Comment: yes both not defined

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the script you are dynamically loading is actually loaded before attempting to use it.

To do so, use `script.onload` to fire a callback once the load is completed.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head') [0].appendChild(script);
script.onload = function () {
  /* jquery dependent code here */
  console.log($);
};
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts) has an example that's more adaptable to a callback you specify -

```
// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts
function loadError (oError) {
  throw new URIError("The script " + oError.target.src + " is not accessible.");
}

function importScript (sSrc, fOnload) {
  var oScript = document.createElement("script");
  oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
  oScript.onerror = loadError;
  if (fOnload) { oScript.onload = fOnload; }
  document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(oScript, document.currentScript);
  oScript.src = sSrc;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks jdp!

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is not working may be caused by jQuery is not loaded yet while browser executing your jQuery code. Use function below to dynamically load jQuery with callback. Put your jQuery code inside a callback function.

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = url;

    if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
        s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            if (event.type === "load" || (/loaded|complete/.test(s.readyState))) {
                s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    }

    document.body.appendChild(s);
}

/* Load up jQuery */
loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
    // Put your jQuery code here.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include jQuery inside the HTML code. jQuery won't work for you because your script is loaded before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Completely false - scripts *can* be dynamically loaded in pages.